# obtain difference between two values of same colum in same pandas dataframe based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, min

I have a pandas dataframes df1 of the format:

```
df1.head()

  action id     ts
0   A   3   2016-01-28 06:14:08.249000
1   B   3   2016-01-28 07:08:49.901000
2   A   4   2016-01-28 10:42:27.228000
3   B   4   2016-01-29 04:15:33.724000
4   B   4   2016-01-29 04:20:33.724000
5   A   5   2016-01-28 11:12:51.892000
```

Data types of columns:
(action: string, id: int,ts: Series(used pandas.to_datetime() to convert it from string))

What I want is, a new column in the same dataframe/ another series which has time difference between action 'A' and action 'B' of the same ids. Only thing being, I need the first occurence of action 'A' as in `min(ts)` for every id and then the subtracted value because the action 'B' has to occur after action 'B' I need to determine the latency between first occurrence of action 'A' and action 'B'

I was able to get it using `groupby()`, `merge()` and `unstack()` but I couldn't get the `min(ts)` in this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way to achieve that would be something like that:

```
In [87]: df
Out[87]:
  action  id                      ts
0      B   3 2016-01-28 06:14:08.249
1      A   3 2016-01-28 07:08:49.901
2      A   4 2016-01-28 10:42:27.228
3      B   4 2016-01-29 04:15:33.724
4      B   4 2016-01-29 04:20:33.724
5      B   5 2016-01-28 11:12:51.892

In [88]: grp = df.groupby(['id'])

In [89]: grp.apply(lambda x: x[x['action'] == 'B'].ts.max()) - \
   ....: grp.apply(lambda x: x[x['action'] == 'A'].ts.min())
Out[89]:
id
3   -1 days +23:05:18.348000
4            17:38:06.496000
5                        NaT
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

NOTE: please pay attention at your sample data set - action `B` for id `3` occured before action `A`

If you want to eliminate NaT's, you can use `.dropna()`:

```
In [82]: result = (grp.apply(lambda x: x[x['action'] == 'B'].ts.max()) - \
   ....:           grp.apply(lambda x: x[x['action'] == 'A'].ts.min())).dropna()

In [83]: result
Out[83]:
id
3   -1 days +23:05:18.348000
4            17:38:06.496000
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know how to use `lambda` properly. I also have another question, how do I eliminate the rows having `Nat` from this output series?

Comment: @ParisaRai, glad i could help. I've updated my answer with "eliminating NaT's"